# Need a bordered scrolling mechanism in pygame

Tags: python, scroll, pygame

I'm quite new to pygame so forgive me if I appear stupid, but I am having problems trying to get a bordered scrolling system - i.e. one that stops when the edge of the background is reached instead of continuously scrolling around.

This is what I have:

```
import pygame
import math
import sys
import random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 728),0,0)
pygame.display.set_caption("Modern Politics")
b1 = "Blank.png"
back = pygame.image.load(b1).convert()
back1 = pygame.image.load(b1).convert()
x=0
y=0
screenWidth = 1024
screenHeight = 728

while True:
    screen.blit(back, (x,y))
    screen.blit(back1, (x-screenWidth,y-screenHeight))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if not hasattr(event, "key"): continue
        if event.key == K_RIGHT:
            x=x-10
        elif event.key == K_LEFT:
            x=x+10
        elif event.key == K_UP:
            y=y+10
        elif event.key == K_DOWN:
            y=y-510
        elif event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            sys.exit(0)

    if x == screenWidth:
        x=0

    if y == screenHeight:
        y=0

    msElapsed = clock.tick(100)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

But that just comes up with a whole heap of problems, as shown in this gif:

https://gyazo.com/f734c9955d52b0fed1e89766013f4122

The (unfinished) picture I am trying to scroll is this 1920x1080 image:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fh2e99nw5jh7eqc/Blank.png?dl=1

How can I make it so that the image stops scrolling and will not scroll when the end of the image is reached? It needs to work both vertically and horizontally.

(By the way I am using Python 3.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is similar to `"following camera"` so you could use `camera offset` if you have more objects on the screen but here I use something different.

You need to compare left,right,top,bottom image border with left,right,top,bottom screen border to stop scrolling

```
# left borders
if x > 0: 
    x = 0

# top borders
if y > 0: 
    y = 0

# right borders
if x+image_width < screen_width: 
    x = screen_width

# bottom borders
if y+image_height < screen_height: 
    y = screen_height
```

I use `pygame.Rect` to use `rect.left` instead of `x` and `rect.right` instead of `x+width` (and `rect.top` instead of `y` and `rect.bottom` instead of `y+height`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# pygame (simple) template 

import pygame

# === CONSTANTS === (UPPER_CASE names)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 1024
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 728

# === CLASSES === (CamelCase names)

  # empty

# === FUNCTIONS ===  (lower_case names)

  # empty

# === MAIN ===

# --- init ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

pygame.display.set_caption("Modern Politics")

# --- objects ---

image_name = "Blank.png"

image = pygame.image.load(image_name).convert()
image_rect = image.get_rect()

speed = 20

change_x = 0
change_y = 0

# --- mainloop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True

while running:

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        # --- global events ---

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

        # --- player events ---

        # KEYDOWN/KEYUP event occurs when key is going down/up (short-time event),
        # not when key is held down/up (long-time event)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                change_x -= speed
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                change_x += speed
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                change_y -= speed
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                change_y += speed

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                change_x += speed
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                change_x -= speed
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                change_y += speed
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                change_y -= speed

    # --- updates (without draws) ---

    # move object
    image_rect.x += change_x
    image_rect.y += change_y

    # check borders

    # right borders (SCREEN_WIDTH)
    if image_rect.right < screen_rect.right:
        image_rect.right = screen_rect.right 

    # left borders (0)
    if image_rect.left > screen_rect.left:
        image_rect.left = screen_rect.left

    # bottom borders (SCREEN_HEIGTH)
    if image_rect.bottom < screen_rect.bottom:
        image_rect.bottom = screen_rect.bottom 

    # left borders (0)
    if image_rect.top > screen_rect.top:
        image_rect.top = screen_rect.top

    # --- draws (without updates) ---

    screen.blit(image, image_rect)

    # human eyes need at least 25FPS to see animation,
    # monitors mostly refresh screen with 60Hz - it means 60FPS.
    clock.tick(30) 

    pygame.display.flip()

# --- the end ---

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly, thank you so much.